# How to do something when available with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, onavailable

I've loaded a `<textarea>` with javascript,

and need to focus on it as soon as it's available.

The live() in jQuery must specify a "type" which doesn't exists in my case.

I need to do something like below:

```
$('#target').onAvailable($('#target').focus());
```

How to implement this with jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387414/is-there-a-onavailable-function-in-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Use a callback:

```
$("...").load("/something/to/load.html", function() {
  $("textarea", this).focus();
});
```

Comment: In fact I'm doing something like :
$('#loader').clone().removeAttr('id').load("Views/chatBox.html").appendTo('body');

Comment: you can still add a callback there